# Habitat - Redundant Synonym Tag or Eliminate?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Biweekly challenge brought attention to [habitat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitat), which not only has no wiki attached, but is only used in a few questions that are also tagged either [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) or [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums).

Of the 7 questions tagged with "habitat":

- 3 are also [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) (for turtles and frogs).
- 3 are also [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums) (for lizards and frogs).
- 1 refers to substrate for both [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) and [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums).

In all of these entries, "habitat" is redundant to [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums).

I don't see a need for the habitat tag; I request it be eliminated or synonym'ed to "terrariums"

Comment: Well you can't keep a hamster in a terrarium, nor a flock of chickens, but they still require habitats, not specifically just a cage. What about in those situations? Or is the cage tag a catch-all in those situations?

Comment: @Piper I think that's what the Enclosure tag was created for.

Comment: Really? Enclosure and Habitat?  Here's the thing - tags are created in order to ease searching on a subject and to associate like items so you can find something similar to what you're looking for.  Habitat, Enclosure and Cage are all pretty much the same thing from a "pet" perspective.  If we're talking "a place a pet inhabits" and link in aquariums and terrariums as part of "habitat", then that invalidates the tab because I'm 99.8% certain no one looking for a "terrarium" via "habitat" wants to read about a question tagged "aquarium".

Comment: As it stands, there are 7 questions tagged with "habitat": 2 which are also tagged "aquarium" (for turtles and frogs), 3 which are also tagged "terrariums" (for lizards and frogs), 1 tagged both "aquarium" and "terrariums" (for substrate), and 1 tagged only "habitat", but mentions "aquarium" in the title.  In all of these entries, "habitat" is redundant.

Comment: @Piper - there are no hamster or chicken questions tagged [tag:habitat] at this time; there are only frog/lizard/turtle questions, where [tag:terrariums] and/or [tag:aquarium] works better.  If you feel [tag:habitat] as a synonym to [tag:terrariums] gets too confusing, them move to delete [tag:habitat].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been completed.

Burma Shave.